# How to populate Dataframe values based on data in another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Lookup DF:

```
+--------------------+------------------+
|         seller_name|             codes|
+--------------------+------------------+
|           BlueR    |[5944, 5813, 5812]|
|           jack     |[4814, 5734, 5968]|
|         Cwireless  |[7349, 7399, 5999]|
|            Tea     |[4899, 5813, 8398]|
```

Base DF:

```
seller_name       | raw_code
    BlueR         | 5813
    jack          | 5968
    Cwireless     | 7865
    Tea           | 5999
    Tea           | 5813
    blueR         | 5678
    jack          | 9999
    Tea           | null
```

If the `seller_name` in the BaseDF is present in the `LookUp data frame`, and if the `raw_code` of the `seller_name` from the Base DF is present in the Lookup DF `codes` then i should retain the same value, but if the raw_code value is something else apart from the elements in the tuple of `LookUp` DF than the `raw_code` value should be replaced by the first element in the tuple for that seller.

`edit:` if the `seller_name` of `base_df` is not present in `lookup` df than the `raw_code` value should be retained as it is.

Expected Output DF:

```
seller_name   | revised_code
blueR         | 5813
jack          | 5968
Cwireless     | 7349
Tea           | 4899
Tea           | 5813
blueR         | 5678
jack          | 4814
Tea           | 4899
```

How can i implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Broadcast the small lookUpDf* and *left join with baseDf*, then use a `udf` function to check whether the `raw_code` is contained in `codes`, if it does return the `raw_code` else first value of `codes` array.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def retainUdf = udf((rawCode: Int, codes:Seq[Int]) => if(codes == null || codes.isEmpty) rawCode else if(codes.contains(rawCode)) rawCode else codes.head)

baseDf.join(broadcast(lookUpDf), Seq("seller_name"), "left")
  .select(col("seller_name"), retainUdf(col("raw_code"), col("codes")).as("raw_code"))
```

which should give you

```
+-----------+--------+
|seller_name|raw_code|
+-----------+--------+
|BlueR      |5813    |
|jack       |5968    |
|Cwireless  |7349    |
|Tea        |4899    |
|Tea        |5813    |
|blueR      |5678    |
|jack       |4814    |
+-----------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh, I have edited the o/p dataframe for seller-name `blueR`, sorry its an error on my part.  Actually, the seller-name `blueR` should be treated as a separate seller than `BlueR` and since the `blueR` is not present in the LookUp DF, its value in the output should not be changed.

Comment: just replace 0 with rawCode in the udf function and you should be fine. I have updated my answer :) @Arjun

Comment: Yeah, i did changed that, Thanks btw :)

Comment: suppose in case of seller-name `blueR` , i.e seller_name which is not present in the lookup DF,  if the raw_code is not exactly 4 digit , than how can I make it NULL, but if its 4 digit I will maintain the same value. @Ramesh

Comment: convert to string and check for length and use the same logic :)

Comment: can you please let me know as what is the issue with this.
`def retainUdf =
    udf(
      (rawCode: Int, codes: Seq[Int]) =>
        if ((codes == null || codes.isEmpty) && len(rawCode) == 4) rawCode
        else if (codes.contains(rawCode)) rawCode
        else if ((codes == null || codes.isEmpty) && len(rawCode) !=4) 0
        else codes.head
    )`

`def len(x: Int, i: Int = 1): Int = if (x < 10) i else len(x / 10, i + 1)`

Comment: You want to return NULL in case the length is not 4 right?

Comment: yes. `if ((codes == null || codes.isEmpty) && len(rawCode) !=4) null`

Comment: use this then `def retainUdf = udf((rawCode: Int, codes:Seq[Int]) => if(codes == null || codes.isEmpty) {if(rawCode.toString.length == 4) rawCode.toString else "NULL"} else if(codes.contains(rawCode)) rawCode.toString else codes.head.toString)`

Comment: suppose if there is no `seller_name` in `BaseDF` but there is a raw_code, how can I maintain the code value in the O/P DF. Currently with the udf its returning `NULL`

Comment: it will return NULL when the length of digit is not 4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172349/discussion-between-arjun-and-ramesh-maharjan).

Comment: the udf is failing due to null pointer exception.
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$retainUdf$1: (string, array<int>) => string)`
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: try printing the values and check for null conditions then. You must be having null in raw_code

Comment: ok. i have another query that i have asked in the chat, can you please check

Comment: incase if the `lookup DF` does not contain a `seller_name` that is present in `Base_DF` than its giving a `NullPointerException` . How do i handle that

Comment: you have already handled for codes but you haven't handled for raw_code. do it as you did for raw_code. Debug in each statement and make the necessary changes. good luck